# Get all the Futures at the same time from a list

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an arraylist of Futures that are executed by an ExecutorService:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.netFixedThreadPoolExecytor(COUNT);
for(myObj : list){
    Future<myObj> future = executor.submit()(() - > some.method(myObj));
    futurelist.add(future);
}
executor.shutdown()
```

I want to be able to call the get() function for all the Futures in the array at the same time so the Thread won't wait for completion until it takes the next element.
The closer I have come is to take all the elements from the array and loop trough them:

```
for(Future f : futurelist) {
    f.get()
}
```

How can I make that all the futures to be executed and completed at the same time ?

Comment: To clarify: you're saying you don't want to wait on the first `Future` if it doesn't finish first, you want to get the result from the first thread to finish so you can process the result as quickly as possible?

Comment: You can't. The end time of a future is determined by the actual runtime of it, not by anything else.

Comment: (Most) Futures don't start computing when you call `get`, they start when you call `submit`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so basically using the ExecutorService, they would start computing at the same time right ?

Comment: So basically, I want to get all the results at the same time, in order to make it faster by getting the results after all the Futures have completed.

Comment: I don't get it.  How is it "faster" to get the results that way, vs. just calling `Future.get()` for each task?  Addendum: are you looking for some sort of asynchronous callback when all threads are complete so you don't have to wait?

Comment: @epushor: Yes.  They all start computing at the same time, and you can't know when they're done other than by calling `get`.

Comment: So basically get() waits until the task is completed so this is taking time. I want somehow to call get() after all the Futures are completed so I don't have to wait for the individual Futures to complete, like calling get() at the same time for all the futures instead of looping... Maybe this is impossible. Maybe It's a dumb question and I overthinked it.

Comment: @epushor, You're saying, you want to _wait_ until all of the futures are completed so that when you call `get()` on them you won't have to wait for them to finish? Even if you could do that, How would it help? You're still waiting for them to finish either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Await termination of your executor service

Your comments indicate that your real goal is to wait until all your submitted tasks have been completed (or cancelled).

You said:

> I want somehow to call get() after all the Futures are completed

A `Future` does not get completed. A `Future` represents:

- The status of a `Callable`/`Runnable` that may have yet to start execution, may be currently executing, or may have ended its execution.
- The result of a `Callable` object's work, returned by its `call` method`. The result payload on the` Future` is empty until the task has completed and returned an object.

To wait until all the submitted tasks are done, you simply need to call `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` on your executor service.

And by the way, you can submit a collection of `Callable` objects to your executor service, if that suits your situation. You will get back a collection of `Future` objects. Getting those `Future` objects does *not* mean the tasks are done, it means the tasks were successfully submitted to an executor service. By the time you get a `Future` back, the task may or may not have started execution.

Here is some example code.

Set up a collection of `Callable` objects. Our example here returns a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html).

```java
int countTasks = 10;
List < Callable < UUID > > tasks = new ArrayList <>( countTasks );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < countTasks ; i++ )
{
    Callable < UUID > c = ( ) -> { return UUID.randomUUID(); };
    tasks.add( c );
}
```

Set up an executor service to perform our tasks on background threads. Establish a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) to be filled with [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) objects representing each of our task’s work.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List < Future < UUID > > futures = null;
```

Ask our executor service to perform those tasks. The service collects the instantiated `Future` objects, returning to us the collection.

```java
try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

We immediately ask the executor service to go into shutdown mode. This stops further tasks from being submitted, but allows already-submitted tasks to continue. We then tell the executor service to wait a certain amount of time for all submitted tasks to complete. We check to see if the termination completed or timed-out.

```java
executorService.shutdown();
try
{
    boolean terminationComleted = executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES );
    if ( ! terminationComleted ) System.out.println( "ERROR - Submitted tasks not completed before time-out. " + Instant.now() );
}
catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

The call to `awaitTermination` blocks until either all tasks are done or the time-out is reached. So beyond that call means the executor service is shutdown. So we can now examine our collection of `Future` objects to see the fruits of our threaded work.

```java
// At this point all submitted tasks are done, and the executor service has ended.
for ( Future < UUID > future : futures )
{
    if ( future.isCancelled() )
    {
        System.out.println( "Oops, task was cancelled. " );
    } else
    {
        try { System.out.println( "future = " + future + "  |  " + future.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Same example, in a complete class, ready to run.

```java
package work.basil.demo.threads;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App4
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App4 app = new App4();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting method `demo`. " + Instant.now() );

        int countTasks = 10;
        List < Callable < UUID > > tasks = new ArrayList <>( countTasks );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < countTasks ; i++ )
        {
            Callable < UUID > c = ( ) -> { return UUID.randomUUID(); };
            tasks.add( c );
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List < Future < UUID > > futures = null;
        try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try
        {
            boolean terminationComleted = executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES );
            if ( ! terminationComleted ) System.out.println( "ERROR - Submitted tasks not completed before time-out. " + Instant.now() );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // At this point all submitted tasks are done, and the executor service has ended.
        for ( Future < UUID > future : futures )
        {
            if ( future.isCancelled() )
            {
                System.out.println( "Oops, task was cancelled. " );
            } else
            {
                try { System.out.println( "future = " + future + "  |  " + future.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting method `demo`. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

You asked:

> How can I make that all the futures to be executed and completed at the same time ?

You cannot.

The first rule of threaded work is that **you do *not* control the threads**. When a thread is scheduled for execution on a core, and for how long that execution runs before suspension, all depends on the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), the host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), and the momentary runtime conditions.

Any of your threads may be started at any time, suspended at any time, and completed at any time. The threads may complete in any order at any time.

You said:

> I want to be able to call the get() function for all the Futures

You can get all the `Future` objects as a collection, as shown in the code above. But each `Future` represents the task to be executed, not the fact that it has been executed. Hence the name `Future`.

You can ask each `Future` object if its task is done or not by calling [`Future#isDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()). If the task has not yet begun execution, you get `false`. If the task is underway (either actively executing on a core or suspended), you get `false`. If the task has completed its work, been cancelled, or failed from a thrown exception, then you get `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible to do directly with `Future`.  I would change your tasks to put their result in a queue, and then just read from the queue.

Maybe something like:

```
List<Object> results = new concurrent list...
Callable<Object> task = new MyTask( results ) // inject list to hold results
List<Callable> taskList = new list...
taskList.add( taskList );
ExecutorService executor = Executors.netFixedThreadPoolExecytor(COUNT);
for(myObj : list){
    Future<myObj> future = executor.submit()(() - > some.method(myObj));
    futurelist.add(future);
}
executor.shutdown();
for( int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++ ) {
   Object result = results.poll();
   // process result...
}
```